# where is the mistake in my calculations of $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1 }^n \frac{a_k}{(n+1-k)(n+2-k)}= \lim_{n\to \infty}a_n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

> if $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}a_n =a$ prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1 }^n \frac{a_k}{(n+1-k)(n+2-k)}= a$

define  $b_{n-1}= a_n - a_{n-1}$ then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty }b_n =0 $

$$ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1 }^n \frac{a_k}{(n+1-k)(n+2-k)}= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1 }^n \frac{a_k}{(n+1-k)}- \frac{a_k}{(n+2-k)}$$ $$ =\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}+a_n -\frac{a_1}{n+1}- \sum\limits_{k=1 }^{n-1} \frac{a_{n+1-k}- a_{n-k}}{k+1} $$ $$= a-\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{a_{k+1}- a_{k}}{n+1-k}=a-\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{b_{k}}{n+1-k}=a-\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{b_{k}}{n+1-k}- b_{n}=$$ $$a- \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k =1} ^n \frac{b_k}{n+1-k}$$

this implies that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k =1} ^n \frac{b_k}{n+1-k}=0$ but this is wrong as [TheSilverDoe](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/594484/thesilverdoe)  pointed out in an answer to [My question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4812183/if-lim-limits-n-to-infty-b-n-0-then-how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-n)

I am confused now by this 3 statements

$$1- \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1 }^n \frac{a_k}{(n+1-k)(n+2-k)}= a$$

$$2- \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1 }^n \frac{a_k}{(n+1-k)(n+2-k)}=a- \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k =1} ^n \frac{b_k}{n+1-k}$$
$$3-\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k =1} ^n \frac{b_k}{n+1-k}\ne 0$$

then which statement is wrong ? and if all of them was correct does this has to do with Riemann rearrangement theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well - if you derived $(2)$ correct, and $(1)$ was proven correct by TheSilverDoe, then the reverse of $(3)$ clearly is also true.

The thinking error you make here is that then also the reverse of $(3)$ follows from the fact that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} b_k = 0$

Obviously, this is not generally true for any $b_k$; see the answer to your other question.

Comment: I still can't understand why is true for any $b_k$ what is the difference between $a_{n+1}- a_n$ and any $b_n \to 0$

Comment: Well, have a look at the answer in the other question - there $b_k$ is roughly $\frac{1}{\ln(k)}$. This cannot equal $a_{k+1}-a_k$ when the row $a_k$ has a finite limit $a$, thus that counter-example does not apply here.

Comment: Note that each value $\frac{1}{\ln(k)}$ repeats $k$ times in the row $(b_j)$ - so when you suppose that $b_k=a_{k+1}-a_k$, then $a_k$ will not tend to any finite value $a$.